# Does kafka do batch processing

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka

We are receiving nightly batch ( One huge file) of 50gb every day into ftp location.

Do Kafka do batch processing ( loading )  and send same batch 50gb ( size ) without splitting  into a consumer ?

Thank you!

Comment: That's is possible. Check out Kafka Connect to load your data into Kafka.

Comment: so , Batch processing is possible with  Kafka Connect . Please clarify .

Comment: Kafka Connect can load your batch data into Kafka. Afterwards you can use Kafka Streams to process this data -- or write a processing application from scratch using Kafka Consumers/Producer. You question is very generic, thus hard to give a detailed answer.